# Remove duplicates from PreparedStatement batch JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a batch which I need to use in order to update a table.
This batch is getting fill by an algorithm that I can't change.
But it is doing something like this:

```
String updateFilter = "UPDATE payload_roas SET filtered = TRUE WHERE asn = ? AND prefix= ? AND max_length = ?";
PreparedStatement ps=  connection.prepareStatement(updateFilter);

            for(int i = 0; i < roas.size(); i++) {
               roa = roas.get(i);
               ps.setLong(1, roa.getAsn());
               ps.setObject(2, roa.getPrefix(), OTHER);
               ps.setInt(3, roa.getMax_length());
               ps.setBoolean(4, roa.isWhitelist);
               ps.setBoolean(5, roa.isFilter);
               ps.addBatch();
        }
```

This batch is quite big ~50K entries.So no surprise that it takes a lot of time when I'm doing executeBatch.
However this ps contains lots of duplicates which means it is doing multiple redundant updates. Is there any way to perform a distinct operation on this batch in order to remove this duplicates?

Comment: would it suffice to avoid duplicates in `roas`? Use a `Set` for/instead of roas - if the class of `roa` has a correctly implemented `equals` there will be no duplicates in the set.

Comment: No I give only a basic idea because I don't have the full algorithm. But what is happen is that there is condition when the algorithm access same cell multiple times. The roas structure itself is actually doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: so how do you want to change it if you do not have it? Only way I see is changing the `addBatch` method, probably by implementing/extending the `PreparedStatement` class....

Comment: if the `roas` does not contain duplicates, how is the same cell (what is a cell?) being accessed multiple times???

Comment: As I said its a part of more complex algorithm but I explain. This "roas" is actual IP prefixes. This list contains prefixes and sub prefixes. The algorithm has a special case that when a flag isFilter is on it going over the roas again trying to find all the ancestors of the specific "roa" and filter them too. Since there is a possibility that to roa has the same ancestor it will add this ancestor twice hence the duplicates. Again I can't change the algorithm and the fact that I get PrepearedStatement which has duplicates in the batch.

Comment: Keep the values of all bind variables already added in the batch. Before adding a new record test if the combination was already set, if so simple skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

```
String updateFilter = "UPDATE payload_roas SET filtered = TRUE WHERE asn = ? AND prefix= ? AND max_length = ?";
PreparedStatement ps=  connection.prepareStatement(updateFilter);
HashSet<String> hashKeys = new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < roas.size(); i++) {
    roa = roas.get(i);
    String key = roa.getAsn() + roa.getPrefix().toString() + roa.getMax_length() + roa.isWhitelist + roa.isFilter;
    if (!hashKeys.contains(key)) {
        hashKeys.add(key);
        ps.setLong(1, roa.getAsn());
        ps.setObject(2, roa.getPrefix(), OTHER);
        ps.setInt(3, roa.getMax_length());
        ps.setBoolean(4, roa.isWhitelist);
        ps.setBoolean(5, roa.isFilter);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
}
```